# How to test Svelte component props with Vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, svelte, vitest, svelte-testing-library

I want to test the props of a [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) component with [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/).

Component:

```
<script>
  export let foo
</script>

<div>{foo}</div>
```

Test:

```js
const { component } = render(MyComponent, { foo: 'bar' })
expect(component.foo).toBe('bar')
```

When I run this test, I get the following error:

> Props cannot be read directly from the component instance
> unless compiling with 'accessors: true' or '<svelte:options accessors/>'

According to [this post](https://github.com/testing-library/svelte-testing-library/issues/196), I should pass `accessors: true` to the `render()` function:

```js
const { component } = render(MyComponent, { accessors: true })
```

However, this doesn't work either and I keep getting the same error.

How can I test Svelte component props?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than always enabling the [`accessors` compiler option](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options) which might negatively impact performance, here's how to do it only a test time. `vitest` automatically sets the boolean environment variable `process.env.TEST=true` when it runs.

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
export default {
  extensions: [`.svelte`, `.svx`, `.md`],

  preprocess: preprocess(),

  compilerOptions: {
    // enable direct prop access for vitest unit tests. now you can do
    // const comp = new Component({ target: document.body, props: {...} })
    // comp.access_some_prop
    accessors: process.env.TEST,
  },

  kit: {
    adapter: adapter(),
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to `svelte.config.js`

```js
compilerOptions: {
  accessors: true
},
```